# Eliminate blobs/speckles in 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D NumPy array containing some "bad" values. I want to cull them.

The neighbours of each bad value are merely "naughty", but I want to cull them as well.

A reliable test for the bad values is to ask:

```
arr<0.1
```

However, the only reliable test (that I can think of) for a naughty value is that it is next to a bad value.

I'm using the following strategy to eliminate the bad and naughy values:

```
import numpy as np

c     = np.random.random(100) #Construct test data

who = np.where(c<0.1)[0]      #Reliable test for bad values
c[who] = 0                    #Zero bad values
#Add and subtract from the indices of the bad values to cull
#their neighbours
wht = who-1; wht = wht[np.logical_and(0<wht,wht<len(c))]; c[wht]=0
wht = who+1; wht = wht[np.logical_and(0<wht,wht<len(c))]; c[wht]=0
wht = who+2; wht = wht[np.logical_and(0<wht,wht<len(c))]; c[wht]=0
wht = who-2; wht = wht[np.logical_and(0<wht,wht<len(c))]; c[wht]=0
```

Unfortunately, the foregoing is quite slow.

Is there a faster way to perform this, or a similar, operation?

Answer (score 2):

One scalable solution for a generic window length of neighbors would be to [`binary-dilate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) the mask of threshold comparisons and then use that mask to set zeros -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

W = 2 # window length of neighbors
thresh = 0.1
mask = c < thresh
kernel = np.ones(2*W+1)
mask_extended = binary_dilation(mask, kernel)
c[mask_extended] = 0
```